# MySQL Trigger - Copy NEW. inserted data compare to existing column values and then insert them to other table if they match

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger on a table (Cvr_flypn_hooks_501_1000) in my MySQL database that does the following:

- Checks the incoming inserted data's (new.user_id) value against the existing data's (post_author_id) value for each row in the table.
- If they match, Copy some of the NEW. INSERTED rows data column values and some of the matching rows existing column data to a single new row in a new table (Cvr_flypn_link_501_1000).
- If they do not match, just allow the NEW. INSERTED data to be inserted into the Cvr_flypn_hooks_501_1000 table.

Issue #1: I think my first issue is in the VALUES section, the last four value options I am trying to select the existing matching values to copy, but the trigger fails to fire when I add the additional existing data to the VALUES array so I think something is up here.

Issue #2: I realize that the query will run against the new data as well but I do not want it to compare its self to itself, I hope that makes sense.

I have included what I have so far below.

```
IF ( EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Cvr_flypn_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id =  new.user_id)) then
          
          INSERT INTO Cvr_flypn_1_link_501_1000 (a_hook_id, a_user_id, a_post_id, a_post_author_id, b_hook_id, b_user_id, b_post_id, b_post_author)

          VALUES (new.hook_id, 
                  new.user_id, 
                  new.post_id, 
                  new.post_author_id,
                  (SELECT hook_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id),
        (SELECT user_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id),
        (SELECT post_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id),
        (SELECT post_author_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id));
END IF
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I am pretty new to programming so please go gently.

Comment: Please add the next time a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remember the next time to provide data in a fiddle like below, so we don't have to recreate it al the time

A Sub-SELECT is only allowed to return 1 value so it is better to add an ORDER BY and A LIMIT 1.

> ```
> CREATE tABLE Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 (hook_id int, user_id int(11) ,post_id int ,post_author_id vaRCHAR(39))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 VALUES (1,1,1,"1")
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE account(hook_id int, user_id int(11) ,post_id int, post_author_id int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Cvr_flypn_1_link_501_1000 (a_hook_id int, a_user_id int(11) ,a_post_id int, a_post_author_id int
> , b_hook_id int, b_user_id int, b_post_id int, b_post_author int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check AFTER  INSERT ON account
>        FOR EACH ROW
>        BEGIN
> IF ( EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id =  new.user_id)) then
>           
>           INSERT INTO Cvr_flypn_1_link_501_1000 (a_hook_id, a_user_id, a_post_id, a_post_author_id, b_hook_id, b_user_id, b_post_id, b_post_author)
>
>           VALUES (new.hook_id, 
>                   new.user_id, 
>                   new.post_id, 
>                   new.post_author_id,
>                   (SELECT hook_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id ORDER BY hook_id DESC),
>         (SELECT user_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id ORDER BY hook_id DESC),
>         (SELECT post_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id ORDER BY hook_id DESC),
>         (SELECT post_author_id FROM Cvr_flypn_1_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id=new.user_id ORDER BY hook_id DESC));
> END IF;
>
>        END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO account VALUES(1,1,1,1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Cvr_flypn_1_link_501_1000
> ```
>
> ```
> a_hook_id | a_user_id | a_post_id | a_post_author_id | b_hook_id | b_user_id | b_post_id | b_post_author
> --------: | --------: | --------: | ---------------: | --------: | --------: | --------: | ------------:
>         1 |         1 |         1 |                1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |             1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b888aa7425ad822d4f4fffc43b16fa87)*

Comment: I will make sure to post in a fiddle format moving forward (the next thing for me to look up is how to do that). I will see if this fixes my problem. Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: you had a small mix up i table names

Comment: So I gave it a try and it is still hanging for some reason. It's weird because I can see your code works, I tried to change the numbers around a bit in the fiddle and it worked. ---- I also tried to create the same table structure you have in your example with the account table and feed it data and it didn't work..... I must be missing something here.

Comment: i can only help you when you make a fiddle with your structire as detailed as needed and see if you can reproduce the problem. if you can you post here the link and i will see, usually it is often only a typo, with tablenames make a SELECT * FROM tablea  and if it yields a result **copy** the table name into the query and with column nmes the same first a select and then **copy** as i said in the comments you had some typos in your sample code from the question